# Node container is crashing without error output

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to run Node container named Client.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent --no-optional

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
    depends_on:
      - users-db

...
...

  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - users
```

All services work just fine on dev server but when I try to containerize Node it crashes as soon as I spin the container. Log gives me this:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.5/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Not very helpful to me as you can imagine. What steps I should take to diagnose where is the issue ?

Comment: Does it just exit with status code 0?

Comment: Yes it is exited with 0.

Comment: Does adding `stdin_open: true` to the `client` configuration help?

Comment: Where exactly the command supposed to be ? I don't suppose in docker-compose file.

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file, directly under the `client:` label.

Comment: Yeah, the container is running, but why ... I never needed `stdin_open: true` before.

Comment: It's an issue in `react-scripts`; the question I link to has some more details.

Comment: Feel free to post it as answer and I'll accept it. React core devs must've made some changes to the library.